# Command Tab Shows Closed Windows?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applications, application-switcher

I just got done setting up my Mac Book.  When I do `command` + `tab` windows that have been closed and are not selectable (Or if I select one nothing happens ...) still show up in the list of apps to choose from.

How do we fix this?

Upon further examination I realized that the windows are actually minimized, and when I select them with `command` + `tab` they don't show?  How do we get them to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the minimized window.  Cmd-Tab is an application switcher, not a window switcher.